# Does Intune support Android apk build with Xamarin using Wrapping Tool?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, intune

I have a project which is build using Xamarin for both iOS and Android. I want to wrap the ipa and apk using the InTune Wrapping tool to upload it to Intune Store for MAM configuration.

Do Intune Wrapping tool support android apk build from Xamarin?
As per below screenshot it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-xamarin#enabling-mam-in-your-android-mobile-app

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Wrapping Tool, and found out that Android build using Wrapping tool is not supported yet. So answer is No.

[image]